# Chromosome information for miRNA

Tags: sam, circos, chromosome-capture

Apologies if this question is previously asked. I have a `BAM` file alignment to `hg19` and miRNA gff3 file from `mirbase` for annotation of BAM file. I want to extract information in the following format (e.g.):

```
miRNA        chr    chr_start    chr_end    expression_count    sequence
hsa-mir-155  chr2       ...         ....         1020            ATGC....
```

I know that I can use htseq-count for BAM annotation and for expression counts but how can I get their chromosomal location. The reason for doing this specific way is that I want to show them in a CIRCOS plot.

Just counting is not the goal, their chromosomal location also needs to be extracted. So just subread/htseq-count is not sufficient for extracting genomic location information.

Previously, I had the same idea about processing the sam records. If I want to annotate chromosomal information with miRNA using .gff file, I have to check for each line in .sam records whether their chr_start and chr_end lie in the bandwidth of start and end of any miRNA in .gff file. This process can be very heavy and slow because .sam records are of more than 5 GB. That's why I want to know if there is any extremely fast and generalized way to do it.

I want to avoid processing sam records in python because my experience with extremely heavy data like fastq or sam in python is not good. I would rather prefer awk/bash or any low-level language.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

you can do `samtools view pathtobamfile`, this will convert the file to `.sam` format and send it to `stdout`, the columns can then be parsed out which contain the information you are after.

Answer (score -1):

The gff should have the coordinates for each feature.  I'd use featureCounts from subread to count up how many reads hit each feature.